# Change background on every visit

Tags: javascript, php, html

How is possible to background changes every time when someone visits page, example:
5 Images, eveytime when I visit page there is another background, that should be in cookies, right?
But I dont want to background change while user is on page, like automatic, just on refresh.
Thanks, any help really appreciated.

Comment: So just selecting a random background on every page load is not applicable? What do you define as _one visit_?

Comment: Its defined backgrounds, sorted by number, and by visit I mean everytime user visits page, I mean user on same computer

Comment: you can use localStorage API, so you store the id of the current background. Then on the onLoad event, you should retrieve the value, select another background and update the id on localStorage.

Comment: Thanks ivan, any examples?

Comment: here is the example:  [w3s](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local)

Comment: Yeah, I understand how it works, but how is possible to use that in my situation? browser storage will need to save numbers, that may be connected with php, so on every visit, number changes and number means the ID of background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for PHP-based solution, you can adjust that code according to your needs:

```
<?php

$backgrounds = array(
    'assets/backgrounds/0.jpg',
    'assets/backgrounds/1.jpg',
    'assets/backgrounds/2.jpg',
    'assets/backgrounds/3.jpg',
    'assets/backgrounds/4.jpg'
);

$expirity = time() + 81400; /* change it to whatever you want */

if ( isset( $_COOKIE['custom_background'] ) ) {

    $backgroundIndex  = ( $_COOKIE['custom_background'] < ( sizeof( $backgrounds ) - 1 ) ) ? $_COOKIE['custom_background'] + 1 : 0;

    setcookie( 'custom_background', $backgroundIndex, $expirity, '/' );

} else {

    setcookie( 'custom_background', 0, $expirity, '/' ); /* initial background will be first array element */

}
```

And then, in your template you can display the background image path like this:

```
echo isset( $_COOKIE['custom_background'] ) ? $backgrounds[ $_COOKIE['custom_background'] ] : 'some-default-background.jpg';
```

Comment: I updated it a little bit, so if you are adding more elements to `$backgrounds` array it should works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript.
First you can read out a cookie. In the cookie you will find the count of visits. With the count of visits you can change the background color.

```js
   var name = "visitCount" + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    var cookieContent;
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) { 
            cookieContent = c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        } else {
            cookieContent = "";
        }
    }
    
    if(cookieContent != "") {
        if(cookieContent == "1") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            document.cookie= "visitCount=2";
        } else if(cookieContent == "2") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            document.cookie= "visitCount=3";
        }
    } else {
        //first visit
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        document.cookie= "visitCount=1";
    }
```

Comment: For some reason it just shows me blank/white color, I used <script>(code)</script>, any help? tnx

Comment: I’d recommend using array accessor operators instead of the overly verbose `if-else` structure: `document.body.style.background=['black','yellow','red'][cookieContent]`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution. Better than the former answers. This uses less code:
At the top of the page (very important)!

```
<?php $bg = array('bglink1', 'bglink2', 'bglink3');$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";?>
```

And the css inside the page

```
body {background:url(<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat center center fixed;}
```

Comment: Yeah, very simple and cool, but I dont want random, I want to background sorts by number, thanks